# spark-redshift: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift, databricks

When I run a query on Aws Redshift from Apache Spark usign the module spark-redshift provided by databricks (https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) I get the following error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error;
```

However if I run the some query directly on redshift with a SQL client (eg. DBeaver) the query executes correctly.

EDIT: I've also tried to execute the same query with the UNLOAD command on redshift and it works correctly.

I'm using the following versions of spark-redshift and redshift driver:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-redshift_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-preview1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
   <artifactId>redshift-jdbc41</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1.1001</version>
</dependency>
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same issue. This error usually occurs when grouping or ordering by a variable constructed in a subquery. I have a feeling that the databricks execution engine chooses which variables to group by, thus ignoring the group bys I pass in in the sql.

Comment: I submitted an issue: https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/337